# Как подставить значение переменной?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть у меня массив состоящий из таких элементов

```
 {id: 1, image: catalog, title: {len0:'Каталог товаров', len1: 'Cataloggg'}, url: './'},
```

я прохожусь мапом и пытаюсь вывести на экран

```
 {props.mainMenuData.map((menu) => (
              <ListItem button key={menu.id}>
                <ListItemText primary={menu.title.len0}  />
              </ListItem>
         ))}
```

проблема в том, что заранее не известно какой будет выбран язык, это может быть либо `len0` либо `len1`. выбранный язык лежит в переменной `dl = "len0";`
как я могу подставить значение переменной `dl` в  `<ListItemText primary={menu.title.вставить значение переменной}  />` ?

Comment: Попробуйте `menu.title[dl]`